# I'm new to VBA and I'm getting a few errors

Tags: excel, vba, email

I have written a code and it pops with error "For without next". Please help me rectify the error.

I'm planning to send bulk emails to 1000 users.

My attempt:

```
 Sub Send_Emails() 
 Dim sh As Worksheet
 Set sh = ThisWorkbook("Send_Emails")
 Dim OA As Object
 Dim msg As Object
 Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
 Dim Last_Row As Integer
 Last_Row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))

 For i = 2 To Last_Row
 Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
 msg.To = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
 msg.CC = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
 msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
 msg.Body = sh.Range("D" & i).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Under your line `msg.Body = sh.Range("D" & i).Value` put `Next i`. The next tells the code where the end of the loop is.

Comment: `Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Send_Emails")`

Comment: practice code indentation

Answer (score 1):

**Some suggestions:**

**1º** Use `Option Explicit` it will help you code better.

**2º** Declare the variables.

**3º** Set the values.

In that order...

Always close the `loops`, `whiles`, `if` statemenet, etc.. As first thing, is easy to forget.

This should work:

```
     Option Explicit
    
     Sub Send_Emails() 
    
     Dim sh As Worksheet, OA As Object
     Dim msg As Object, Last_Row As Integer
     
     Last_Row = Application.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
     Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Send_Emails")
     Set OA = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    
     For i = 2 To Last_Row
      
        Set msg = OA.CreateItem(0)
        msg.To = sh.Range("A" & i).Value
        msg.CC = sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        msg.Subject = sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        msg.Body = sh.Range("D" & i).Value
    
      Next i
    
    End Sub
```